# Trying to send email using gmail from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, gmail

I am trying to send email from a ASP.MVC application using gmail.

I have set account to "Any Address"
and clicked "Requires SMTP Authentication"

if I use port 25 I get error 
"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required."

if I use port 465 I get a timeout error "The operation has timed out."

```
           Using m As Net.Mail.MailMessage = New Net.Mail.MailMessage("any@address.net.au", "any@address.net.au")
            m.Subject = "test"
            m.Body = "I am testing"
            Using c As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient
                c.Send(m)
            End Using
        End Using
```

My webconfig

```
 <mailSettings>"
  <smtp from="default@account.com.au" >
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com"  enableSsl="true"  password="mypassword" port="465" userName="info@mygmailaccount.com" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Any ideas
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using port 587 as shown below:

```
  <smtp from="support@test.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" userName="yourusername@gmail.com" password="yourpassword.123" />
  </smtp>
```

Comment: Does not workAdditional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at